# Accessing values referenced by other columns in pandas

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a pandas dataframe as shown here. There are many more columns in the dataframe that are not necessary for this task.

```
sentence  token     tokenID    entity1     entity2    relation
   1         a          0         NaN        NaN       NaN
   1         b          1         NaN        NaN       NaN
   1         c          2         NaN        NaN       NaN
   1         d          3         NaN        NaN       NaN
   1         e          4         NaN        NaN       NaN
   1         f          5         NaN        NaN       NaN
   1         g          6         NaN        NaN       NaN
   1         h          7         NaN        NaN       NaN
   1        NaN        NaN         0          4         A
   1        NaN        NaN         2          6         B
```

All tokens with the same value for sentence belong to the same sentence.

The two rows below contain information regarding the sentences. The values in `entity1` (and `entity2`) represent the relevant `tokenID`. In this case `entity1=0`, which means the relevant token is the one with `tokenID=0`.

Now I want to return a list with every single relation in the frame:

```
[sentence, token1, token2, relation]
```

Meaning in my example:

```
[1, a, e, A] and [1, c, g, B]
```

I tried to write a function:

```
def sol():
    op = [sentence, entity1, entity2, relations]
    mi = df[["sentence","entity1","entity2"]]
    ba = df.loc[df.sentence.isin(mi.sentence) & df.tokenID.isin(mia.entity1)]
    ba2 = df.loc[df.sentence.isin(mi.sentence) & df.tokenID.isin(mia.entity2)]
    op[1] = ba.token
    op[2] = ba2.token
```

but it didn't work as I planned.

Any ideas?

Comment: what is the expected output and what is the actual output?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `pandas.merge`. First break your dataset into two parts -

1. Token Mapping
2. Relations

Then merge relations with token mapping to get the desired output -

```
df_token_map = df[df['token'].notnull()][['sentence', 'token', 'tokenID']]
df_relation_map = df[df['relation'].notnull()][['sentence', 'entity1', 'entity2', 'relation']]

df_relation_map = df_relation_map.rename(index=str, columns={'entity1' : 'tokenID'}).merge(df_token_map.rename(index=str, columns={'token':'entity1'}), on=['sentence','tokenID'], how='left').drop('tokenID', axis=1)

df_relation_map = df_relation_map.rename(index=str, columns={'entity2' : 'tokenID'}).merge(df_token_map.rename(index=str, columns={'token':'entity2'}), on=['sentence','tokenID'], how='left').drop('tokenID', axis=1)
df_relation_map[['sentence', 'entity1', 'entity2', 'relation']]
```

Comment: Yes, this did work and it's also quite fast on the dataset. Thank you for your help!

Answer (score 1):

This is one way via 2 self-merges.

```
res = df.loc[:, ['entity1', 'entity2', 'relation']].dropna()\
        .merge(df[['sentence', 'token', 'tokenID']].dropna(),
               how='left', left_on='entity1', right_on='tokenID')\
        .merge(df[['sentence', 'token', 'tokenID']].dropna(),
               how='left', left_on='entity2', right_on='tokenID')

lst = res[['sentence_x', 'token_x', 'token_y', 'relation']].values.tolist()

[[1, 'a', 'e', 'A'],
 [1, 'c', 'g', 'B']]
```

Note it's not clear what precisely you want in the case of multiple sentences.

Answer (score 1):

1.create a map for token and token ID

2.replace for entity columns

try this,

```
df_temp=df[df['token'].isnull()] 
df_temp=df_temp[['sentence','entity1','entity2','relation']]
z=df[df['token'].notnull()]
dic=dict(zip(z['tokenID'],z['token']))#creaing dictionary
df_temp['entity1']=df_temp['entity1'].map(dic) #mapping 
df_temp['entity2']=df_temp['entity2'].map(dic) #mapping 
print df_temp.values
```

Output

> [[1 'a' 'e' 'A']
>
> [1 'c' 'g' 'B']]